# Why does ASP.NET Core not process my requests in parallel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple action like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> GetHtml()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Run=======================================================");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("End=======================================================");
    return "ok";
}
```

I open three windows quickly, and go to the URL. I expected the result to look like:

```
Run=======================================================
Run=======================================================
Run=======================================================
End=======================================================
End=======================================================
End=======================================================
```

But, It's not! Instead, the result was:

```
Run=======================================================
End=======================================================
Run=======================================================
End=======================================================
Run=======================================================
End=======================================================
```

In addition, when the first run is finished, the second request begins. Why?

Comment: Can you try with 3 different browsers?

Comment: Okay. When I ran different browsers. It ran correctly. But why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as per my suggestion in the comment you tried with 3 different browsers and it worked as expected. So the issue was from the browser side. Browsers has their limits regarding how they manage connection to the same hostname. See [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) for more info